# Wine is not working under 18.04 LTS

Tags: wine, 18.04

Wine (Stable) and (Development) appear in Ubuntu 18.04 Archive, but will not launch?

Comment: If you run `wine` in Terminal, what's the output?

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy wine-stable`?

Comment: If I input Wine in terminal the output is Command 'wine' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install wine-development
sudo apt install wine-stable  .... but I have done this several times and also installed direct from wine hq with no result.

Comment: apt-cache policy wine-stable output.. Installed:  3.0.0~xenial

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry but I cant make any sense of this forum mechanism? Ive been using Ubuntu SUCCESSFULLY for 10yrs, now 18.04 LTS is full of problems, nothing works, Installers crash, its been broken on purpose, microsoft is probably involved some where. Thank for your time.

Comment: @jilees178 What doesn't make sense? There are many [help](https://askubuntu.com/help) pages available. We are also here to help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have some bad items in your sources list.  If you are running Ubuntu, wine-stable shouldn't have a xenial version.  The baseline version of wine-stable in 18.04 is 3.0-1ubuntu1.

I suggest removing all ppas that have to do with wine and try installing it from the baseline repos.